# Create an image made of many circles

Tags: python, performance, image

I have written some Python code for creating an image made of lots of circles. It works, but I wonder if it could be made faster, shorter or more pythonic somehow.

Example image (took 28 seconds):

[image: example image]

```py
from PIL import Image
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime


def circle(data, center, radius, color, size):
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if (x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2 <= radius ** 2:
                data[x * size + y] = color
    return data


def main():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    size = 500
    circle_amount = 200
    data = [(0, 0, 0)] * size ** 2
    img = Image.new("RGB", (size, size), "black")
    for _ in range(circle_amount):
        data = circle(data, (randint(0, size), randint(0, size)), randint(0, max(size, size)) / randint(5, 10), (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)), size)
    img.putdata(data)
    img.save("image.png")
    print(f"Time needed: {datetime.now() - start_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't set the data. Don't iterate over pixels. Iterate over circles only and use PIL's own drawing facilities:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from random import randint, randrange


def circle(draw: ImageDraw, size: int) -> None:
    xc, yc = randrange(size), randrange(size)
    radius = randrange(size) / randint(5, 10)
    color = randrange(256), randrange(256), randrange(256)

    draw.ellipse(
        xy=(
            xc - radius, yc - radius,
            xc + radius, yc + radius,
        ),
        fill=color,
    )


def main():
    size = 500
    circle_amount = 100_000
    img: Image = Image.new("RGB", (size, size), "black")
    draw: ImageDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    for _ in range(circle_amount):
        circle(draw, size)

    img.save("image.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This took about one second for a hundred thousand circles. We expect this approach to be much faster because internally it's not implemented in Python, but rather [in C](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/libImaging/Draw.c#L1437):

```c
static int
ellipseNew(
    Imaging im,
    int x0,
    int y0,
    int x1,
    int y1,
    const void *ink_,
    int fill,
    int width,
    int op) {
    DRAW *draw;
    INT32 ink;
    DRAWINIT();

    int a = x1 - x0;
    int b = y1 - y0;
    if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (fill) {
        width = a + b;
    }

    ellipse_state st;
    ellipse_init(&st, a, b, width);
    int32_t X0, Y, X1;
    while (ellipse_next(&st, &X0, &Y, &X1) != -1) {
        draw->hline(im, x0 + (X0 + a) / 2, y0 + (Y + b) / 2, x0 + (X1 + a) / 2, ink);
    }
    return 0;
}
```